# Analytically determining whether a laser beam will hit a moving target

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry

I'm tinkering on a space-related computer game. The objects of the game are in 3D space and their motions are defined by 3 3D vectors:

${vector}\ V: \{X, Y, Z\} \\
{motion}\ M: \{V_{position}, V_{speed}, V_{acceleration}\}$

There are space ships and occasionally they fire their lasers at what they estimate their targets motion to be:

$M_{source} \rightarrow M_{estimated\ target}$

I'm including light speed in the simulation (but ignoring relativity for foreseeable future). To determine if a laser beam will hit a target during some time interval, I'm currently looking to analyze the function:

$P(t-T(t)),\ where: \\
P(t) = |P_{real\ target}(t)-P_{estimated\ target}(t)| \\
T(t) = (|P_{real\ target}(t)-P_{source}(t)|)/lightspeed$

To paraphrase, analyzing the difference between estimated target position and real target position as they were when the laser would have needed to have been fired for the beam to reach the target at current time.

For the $|P_2(t) - P_1(t)|$ bits, I've just subtracted the vectors and found the length of the vector, which expands into:

$L(t)=\sqrt{0.25X''t^4+X'X''t^3+(X'^2+XX'')t^2+2XX't + X^2 + ... (same\ for\ Y,Z)}$

I'd like solve inequalities such as $P(t-T(t) < l$ for t. With my elementary algebra skills and help from wikipedia, I've tried to find the roots of the polynomial(s) and somehow expand from there but I'm not sure what to do with the square roots and the composition of polynomials in $P(t-T(t))$.

How should I go about doing that? I don't even know which direction to look really :(

Admittedly, I don't really know what I'm doing so maybe there is a better way of approaching this problem altogether?